# Field degrees of freedom from equations of motion and higher spin

Tags: lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, constrained-dynamics, degrees-of-freedom, higher-spin

It is my understanding that we compute the number of degrees of freedom of a quantum field as the number of its components minus the number of non trivial equations we get by taking the divergence of the equation of motion. Is that true? How these equation can be interpreted in terms of Hamiltonian constraints?

For instance for a vector field $A_{\mu}$ with a general Lagrangian $$\mathcal{L}[A_{\mu}]=-\frac{1}{4}F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+stuff[A_{\mu}]$$ we have the equations of motion $\partial_{\nu}F^{\mu\nu}+\frac{\delta}{\delta A_{\mu}}stuff[A_{\mu}]=0$. Taking the divergence (which must be zero since it is the divergence of zero) we have the non trivial condition: $$\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta}{\delta A_{\mu}}stuff[A_{\mu}]=0$$ which removes one degree of freedom, so that the field $A_{\mu}$ propagates indeed 3 degrees of freedom.

Now I would expect that the same works with fields that are tensors of higher rank (i.e. higher spin: spin 2, spin 3 etc). Do we simply get as many non trivial equations as the rank of the tensor representing the field?

Comment: Note that in your vector field example the counting of DOF depends on whether there is a gauge symmetry or not. Consider making your vector field example crystal clear before asking about higher spin, where gauge symmetry is more complicated.

Comment: Yeah I agree that additional symmetries will make "vanish" some of the degree of freedom. What I meant by higher rank tensor is higher spin fields. I cannot understand what else could not be clear in my question. Thanks anyway for the feedback. Edit: I found and edited an error in the last question, now it should be clear hopefully!

Comment: Your equation $\partial_{\mu}\frac{\delta}{\delta A_{\mu}}stuff[A_{\mu}]=0$ does not directly get rid of degrees of freedom of $A$. This is just the current conservation for the matter fields and it has no remaining dependence on $A$.

Comment: Well for instance in the Proca case (where $stuff[A_{\mu}]=m^2A_{\mu}A^{\mu}$) the equation depends on $A_{\mu}$:  $\partial_{\mu}A^{\mu}=0$, which removes one of the four degrees of freedom.